# How to access list elements in R?

Tags: r, list

I have a list named as ***change_points*** composed of 6 rows with 1 or 2 elements in each. It looks like this:
[image]

My question is, how can I access just 654 from 2nd row? Or any single value or any row.

I've search over SO, and I've only come up with  `` sapply(change_points,`[`,c(1)) ``  which shows me the first element of each row.

Any guidance please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no row attribute in a `list`.  A `list` can have a `length` attribute which is 6 (based on the image).  So, if we need to extract the value 654, which is the 2nd element of the vector which is the 2nd element of the `list`

```
change_points[[2]][2]
```

The `change_points[[2]]` extracts the 2nd list element as a `vector` and then use `[2]` to extract the 2nd element of the `vector`

---

When we specify the index as `1`, it returns the first element only

```
sapply(change_points,`[`, 1)
```

Here, the `sapply` is looping over all the `list` elements and extracting the 1st element.  If it should be the second element, change the 1 to 2.  But, we only need the value of the second list element, so looping over all elements is not needed